# How to determine the direction of moments (confusion)?

Tags: torque, moment

My teacher is showing me a few ways that I can calculate moment and its direction. In this example, she is going to use the principle of moments to solve this (ie resolving into components)

[image]

But what I have the most trouble is, determining the direction of the moment.

I have read the description from the wikipedia (right hand grip rule), but after trying and trying I have failed to understand why the force x is negative? We are using a convention that anti-clockwise = positive and clockwise = negative. Can someone explain and help me visualise this?

update:

I included a picture of my hand (RHGR) to show you what I mean. And as you can see it is in anticlockwise

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As with most quantities involved with rotation, the vector representing moment (or torque) is defined as being along the axis of rotation.  (The axis is usually the one direction associated with a rotating object which does not change with time.)  Th choice of a right-hand-rule is an arbitrary (but customary) choice.  It is easy to remember.  Curl your right hand fingers around the axis in the direction of the rotation (which will be caused by the torque).  Then the right hand thumb gives the direction (along the axis) for the vector which represents the torque.  (The same rule can be used for angle, angular velocity, angular acceleration, and angular momentum.) Whether the components of the vectors are positive or negative depends on your choice of a coordinate system.
Here is my preferred definition of torque:  Torque is the work per unit angle of rotation (as in Joules/radian) which can be done by a force which is acting in a manner that tends to cause a rotation. This reminds you that you need the component of the force which can do work and a distance.